# Cannot Get INS for 2Checkout Paymet

Tags: integration, payment, 2checkout

I'm currently trying 2CO payment integration to my website with 2CO demo account. I was setting up my account in accordance with the requirements that I need. But when I do the payment process and finish it, I did not get a notification (INS). I had to fill INS URL in INS setting and I use form basic payment with plug and play parameters. So, why I can't get notification and please tell me how to set my 2CO account that can get INS. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

2Checkout INS messages are not sent on demo sales so if you are also utilizing the [Instant Notification Service (INS)](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/notifications/), you can use the [INS testing tool](http://developers.2checkout.com/inss) to simulate the INS messages you are listening for.

Please feel free to also contact techsupport@2checkout.com if you need assistance with testing your integration.

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of the demo sale, doesn't it ? :/ I seen some of the strangest practices during the last 4 weeks while trying to setup 2CO. Including but not limited to creating a 2CO account for each and every of my 40 domains. But also permanently locking accounts with money in it, because of inactivity.

Comment: That seriously defies the point of a test sale!! The point of test sale is to make sure everything will work fine in the live environment.. !!!!!

Comment: AND PLEASE MENTION THIS IN YOUR DOCUMENTATION!!! WHOLE DAY WASTED TRYING TO DEBUG THIS!!!!

Comment: @NeiL I guess it's now located at https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/notifications/ins_test

Comment: @4unkur Its under development.

Answer (score 0):

I created an INS post url and tested on http://developers.2checkout.com/inss  and it worked. But it is not sending HTTP POST request on clicking of a sale's "Recurring-Installment-success" option.

I am doing this on a sandbox account and I have made Demo setting as OFF .

As per INS Documents, INS notifications are not sent on demo sales. I hope after making demo setting off, a sale is no more a demo sale.